# Objective C: unrecognized selector sent to Subclass of UIViewController Subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, selector

is almost a week that i can't fix a brain painful problem:

I have a UIViewController subclass named StreamingViewControllerCommon that implement this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL isMusicStopped;
```

and of course i @synthesize it in the .m file

then i have 2 subclasses of this class: `Listen_UIViewController` and `LastNews_UIViewController` that modify (not calling `self.isMusicStopped` but accessing directly to it) the var `isMusicStopped`.

In another Class i have a NSMutableDictionary that contains 2 instance (1 for each class) of these two classes but when i try to do this:

```
if (streamingViews){
        for(StreamingViewControllerCommon* aView in streamingViews){
            BOOL stopped = aView.isMusicStopped;
            NSLog(@"%@",stopped);
            if(stopped){
                [aView closeStream];
                [streamingViews removeObjectForKey:[aView class]];
                [aView release];
                aView = nil;
            }
        }
    }
```

i obtain this error:

```
2011-02-08 15:55:09.760 ProjectName[6182:307] +[LastNews_UIViewController isMusicStopped]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2143c
2011-02-08 15:55:09.768 ProjectName[6182:307] CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: +[LastNews_UIViewController isMusicStopped]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2143c
```

But the weird thing is that in the StreamingViewControllerCommon implement also these methods:

```
-(void) destroyStreamer{
}

-(void) closeStream{
    [self destroyStreamer];
}
```

and when i do:

```
NSMutableArray* keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[streamingViews allKeys]];
    [keys removeObject:[thisView class]];
    NSMutableArray *tmp =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[streamingViews objectsForKeys:keys notFoundMarker:@"404"]];
    if (tmp){
        for (StreamingViewControllerCommon* vc in tmp)
            [vc closeStream];
        [tmp release];
    }

    [streamingViews removeObjectsForKeys:keys];
```

i am not getting any error and the subclasse's overridden closeStream methods are right called.

What am i doing wrong?

Best Regards, Antonio

EDIT: As I wrote in the comment: Changing this:

```
if (streamingViews){
        for(StreamingViewControllerCommon* aView in streamingViews){
            BOOL stopped = aView.isMusicStopped;
            NSLog(@"%@",stopped);
            if(stopped){
                [aView closeStream];
                [streamingViews removeObjectForKey:[aView class]];
                [aView release];
                aView = nil;
            }
        }
    }
```

in this:

```
if (streamingViews){
        for (id aViewClass in streamingViews){
            StreamingViewControllerCommon* aView = [[streamingViews objectForKey:aViewClass] retain]; 
            //NSLog(@"%@",aView.isMusicStopped);
            if(aView.isMusicStopped){
            [aView closeStream];
            [streamingViews removeObjectForKey:aViewClass];
            [aView release];
            aView = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Did the trick :P The for each cycle of a NSDictionary returns its keys not the objects and, since i was using the Class of objects as key i was obtaining that weird exception

Comment: Ok what a fool... Thx to your comment Chuck i understood that what i was getting from the foreach cycle were the keys, not the objects and, since i was using the Classes as keys it returned that error... Changing the cycle in: for (id aViewClass in streamingViews){
   StreamingViewControllerCommon* aView = [[streamingViews objectForKey:aViewClass] retain]; 
   //NSLog(@"%@",aView.isMusicStopped);
   if(aView.isMusicStopped){
    [aView closeStream];
    [streamingViews removeObjectForKey:aViewClass];
    [aView release];
    aView = nil;
   }
  }
did the trick :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, it looks like `streamingViews` contains not an instance of LastNews_UIViewController, but the class itself. That's what the plus sign in `+[LastNews_UIViewController isMusicStopped]` signifies.

Comment: and so why the same thing doesn't happen within the other method? I mean why exceptions are not thrown when i do [vc closeStream] ?